# Reference a column by using a string from an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table (called DGHG) containing a lot of data in an external workbook.
simplified it is a little like this:

```
Member   |   Team   |   Score1  |

Anne     |   1      |   80      |
Rick     |   1      |   100     |
John     |   2      |   60      |
Eric     |   2      |   70      |
```

in an external workbook I want to get an average of the score but only for team 1. I can do that like this:

```
=SUMIF((data.xlsx!DGHG[[#Data],[Team]]),"1",(data.xlsx!DGHG[[#Data],[Score1]]))/COUNTIF((data.xlsx!DGHG[[#Data],[Team]]),"1")
```

this works but I have to create 882 variations of this formula. 
Is there a way how i can reference the column `Score1` by naming it in an adjacent cell (say, B1) and pointing the formula toward it?

I suspect I might need to use INDIRECT( (source: [Excel - Reference a column for a formula, using input from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890931/excel-reference-a-column-for-a-formula-using-input-from-a-cell)) but I cannot get the syntax right for this case.

Comment: yes, i have all of them open

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use INDIRECT, or you could leap straight in with a pivot table. Set the rows to be the Team ID, and set the values to be the average of the score value

Sorry, got you now. In the following, F2 has the team column letter, F3 the score column, G2 the team index

```
=SUMIF(
    INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F2,":",F2)),
    G2,
    INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F3,":",F3))
    ) / COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F2,":",F2)),G2)
```

Comment: what would be the right syntax in this case? sadly, i can't get it to work

Comment: Assuming your source table is in columns A->C, rows 1->13. Make a new table with cols Team and AvScore. Prepopulate Team IDs from the source table (you can use the advanced filtering to make a copied list of unique entries if they're not a continuous range). For example, this is in column G on the same sheet (just to make the formula more readible. Col H can then be the same formula:

    =sumif($b$2:$b$13,g2,$c$2:$c$13)/countif($b$2:$b$13,g2)

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have been more clear. I meant the syntax for the INDIRECT function.
The table is referenced by a lot of worksheets and i can't change it or make a copy of it since the contents might change in the future

Comment: Sorry, got you now:

F2 has the team column letter, F3 the score column, G2 the team index

=SUMIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F2,":",F2)),G2,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F3,":",F3)))/COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(F2,":",F2)),G2)